# Why is this repeat-loop not stopping?

Tags: swift, function, repeat

He guys, I wrote this little code to simulate the catching of Pokemon's, there are three types of poke balls and two types of berries. I wanted to repeat the using of berries to decrease the kp of the Pokemon to catch it with a pokeball which is strong enough after the decrease.
The function is starting but the repeat loop is not stopping! The Pokemon is caught but it doesn't stopp. Can someone help me to make this code working? Thanks in advance!

```
struct Pokeball {
    var name: String
    var power: Int
}
var pokeball = Pokeball(name: "Pokeball", power: 5)
var superball = Pokeball(name: "superball", power: 7)
var hyperball = Pokeball(name: "Hyperball", power: 10)

struct Berries {
    var name: String
    var power: Int
}
var himmihberry = Berries(name: "himmihberry", power: 1)
var goldenBerry = Berries(name: "golden Berry", power: 3)

struct Pokemon {
    var name: String
    var wp: Int
    var kp: Int
}
var glumanda = Pokemon(name: "Glumanda", wp: 10, kp: 6)
var dialga = Pokemon(name: "Dialga", wp: 30, kp: 25)

struct Poketrainer {
    var name: String
    var balls: Int
    var berries: Int
    var pokemons: [Pokemon]
    mutating func Catching(pokemonToCatch: Pokemon, usingBall: Pokeball, usedBerry: Berries) {
        var pokemonToCatch = pokemonToCatch
        repeat {
            print("\(name) is using \(usedBerry.name)...")
            pokemonToCatch.kp -= usedBerry.power
            berries -= 1
            
            print("\(name) is throwing a \(usingBall.name) to catch \(pokemonToCatch.name)")
            if usingBall.power > pokemonToCatch.kp {
                pokemons.append(pokemonToCatch)
                print("\(pokemonToCatch.name) was caught!")
                balls -= 1
            } else {
                print("Pokemon was to strong...")
            }
            
        } while balls > 0 || pokemons.count < 0
                print("Hunt is over...")
            }
    }
    
    
var ash = Poketrainer(name: "Ash", balls: 3, berries: 5, pokemons: [])
ash.Catching(pokemonToCatch: glumanda, usingBall: superball, usedBerry: himmihberry)
print("balls: \(ash.balls), pokemon: \(ash.pokemons.count)")
```

Comment: what are the values of 'balls' and 'pokemon.count' within the loop?

Comment: try your loop with just the balls condition and likewise with only pokemon.count. Either of those variables are probably not getting updated

Comment: Both the variables that are used in the `while` condition, balls and pokemons, are updated inside the same `if` condition so I would focus on that condition `if usingBall.power > pokemonToCatch.kp {` because that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do `balls -= 1` right after `print("Pokemon was too strong")`. I'm assuming the ball is consumed whether you caught the pokemon or not